# Oracle apex form doesent INSERT/UPDATE or Create entry in database

Tags: oracle-apex

Hi everyone so I have a problem with Oracle Apex, I created a master-detail with a from and everything worked fine. Then I created another page within the same app but nothing connected to the page mentioned before, and now nothing on the first page works. When I try to create an entry the form opens I can type anything in and when I click "create" the form closes and nothing happens. Nothing is inserted into the database, edit also doesn't work as well ass deletes everything looks perfect till the form closes, the region refreshes but nothing actually happens.

1. No error shows up in the app or in the console/debugger
2. I checked the form processes and the DML is there.
3. Tried to manually set value in SQL Workshop and that works, I'm able to manually insert rows but not through the form.

Please help this is for my final project and I need this to work.
Thank you in advance!

Edit: 4) Also saw that no button works on the form. I have a combination of form + interactive grid and the grid usualy has like a page navigation buttons for previous/ next and those dont work aswell. So maybe i try deleting and re creating all the buttons?

EDIT2: Managed to fix it, and found that I was somehow missing the *Close Dialog* process in my form. Added it and now everything works!

Comment: It is kind of difficult to debug something you can't see; if I were you, I'd recreate it. That's a **report with a form** "master-detail" you're talking about, right? If so, use the Wizard and start over. Apex will create everything right. Then, when you make it work, make it fancy (i.e. fix labels, items' positions etc.).

Comment: Yes i guess thats the only way to do it , but i have a ungodly amount of dynamic actions on it and spent a whole day doing that report with form to look presentable. And spending another day to fix it would be worse case scenario. Wish i could give you my workspace info so you can take a look. ( the amount of time i spent on it is only because im very new to it and i take a bit of time to get something right ! xD

Comment: Do as I said - use the Wizard and create new set of pages (IR and Form). Open two browsers and in one of them open your old (non-working) pages; another will be used to open your new (working) pages. Then compare them both; pay attention to processes (especially **Pre-rendering** in a form), fix if there's something wrong.

Comment: By default APEX takes regular backups of the app - I suggest restoring the latest backups to all different application id and restarting from your last working version.

Comment: I will try the Littlefoot way first as im 1000% sure there is a button issue or i accidentaly moved a process where iz shouldnt be. If that doesent work will restore it to a working backup. Thank you for the help !

Comment: Fixed it, was missing a process *Close Dialog* in form processes

Comment: Good to hear it worked. You can close your own question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Close dialog* process in the form page was missing, recreated it from a different form, and now everything works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).